# How can i use "console" tab on google chrome selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

This is my script:

1. Open Chrome on selenium
2. Open chrome-devtool
3. Run a command from "Console"
4. Close chrome-devtool

Now I Can open chrome and chrome-devtool but i can't Run a command from "Console" and Close chrome-devtool

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to execute javascript in the console?